# cashondelivery.html Override template is not working

Tags: magento2, template-override

I put some code in below file.

> File path:
>   vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cashondelivery.html

It is working fine in this file. The same code put here,

> File path:
>   app/design/frontend/Magento/xxxx/Magento_OfflinePayments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cashondelivery.html

But not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have defined Magento/xxxx theme in your configuration, also when overriding a template in your theme, the path should be: **Magento_OfflinePayments/web/template/payment/cashondelivery.html**

Comment: Thank you it is working fine. change path to Magento_OfflinePayments/web/template/payment/cashondelivery.html